# How to find previous month for database string 'JAN-11'?

Tags: sql, date

I have a database column `p_name` containing month data in the form `MMM-YY` (such as 'JAN-11'). It is of type `varchar`. How can I find the previous month (in the example 'Dec-10') for this data?

Comment: Stating which database you are using would be helpful, as the date functions available vary between databases.

Answer (score 3):

*Assuming your using SQL Server:*

Convert `JAN-11` into a `datetime` object, subtract 1 month, then convert back into your string format.

```
declare @date nvarchar(10) = 'JAN-11'

declare @dt datetime = '1-' + @date --Converts to datetime
SET @dt = DATEADD(m, -1, @dt) --Subtracts 1 month

RETURN UPPER(REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(9), @dt, 6), 6), ' ', '-'))
--Returns "DEC-10"
```

You could then put this logic into a [User defined function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175085%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), and call it like:

```
SELECT dbo.PreviousMonth("JAN-11")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @pramDate varchar(10)
set @pramDate = '01/05/2012'

SELECT UPPER(LEFT(DateName( month,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, CONVERT(datetime,@pramDate)) - 1, 0)),3)) + 
   '-' + substring(DateName( Year, CONVERT(datetime,@pramDate) ) ,3,4)
```

just refer to the example and you'll get what you are lookiing for